# Multiple file upload in PHP, getting index of file

Tags: php, html

I have a form to upload multiple files, my input already has the name files[], the issue is that i set the index for each input as I need it to identify the file they're uploading.

Is there a way to get that index sent while processing the upload in PHP.

I already have the form created with the specific id needed, I can upload the file, I have no problem uploading it, I want the index of the name in the HTML form to identify it.

```html
<input type="file" name="expediente[1]" class="custom-file-input form-control" multiple="false" id="exp1">
<label class="custom-file-label" for="exp1">ID</label>

<input type="file" name="expediente[2]" class="custom-file-input form-control" multiple="false" id="exp2">
<label class="custom-file-label" for="exp2">PHOTO</label>

<input type="file" name="expediente[4]" class="custom-file-input form-control" multiple="false" id="exp4">
<label class="custom-file-label" for="exp2">PROFILE</label>
```

I want to get the index of the array expediente[**this index right here**], to insert it later as an identifier in the database, is there a way to get it. 
The form is dynamically generated depending on user information, so the indexes aren't consecutive.
I have a workaround sending a hidden input with the id, but it involves disabling the hidden inputs, and it sometimes fails.

I'm using ajaxForm to send the parameters to the php processing script.

Comment: Just change the input name to be the same on each input element like for example `name="expediente[]"` that way you will have an array of files posted and can access the position you need

Comment: Why did you MISS `name="expediente[3]"`

Comment: You already have an array in `$_POST` called `$_POST['expediente']` which should be an array. So the index you want is the index number of that array

Comment: It's not missed that index is an ID, which i want to get to insert it as an identifier in the database. my form could have expediente[3],expediente[4], or expediente[1],expediente[4]. The point is I want to get that index since is an unique ID to identify the type of file I'm uploading.

Comment: You can't use that index as the ID. It needs to be sequential. Set a separate field containing the ID